# Does anyone know what happened to the official FastCGI website?

Tags: fastcgi

Ok, I know this is really off-topic (and down-vote me if you want for it), but I can't find anywhere else with a large enough group of programmers or general people in the know to ask this. Does anyone know what happened to the official FastCGI website? It's been replaced by the website of a New York charity (screenshot [here](http://tinypic.com/r/4tlzic/7))

The reason I ask is because I was looking to download the FastCGI developer's kit they wrote, as well as read the FastCGI specification, but it's now all gone. If anyone has access to the latest FastCGI dev kit and the FastCGI specification, could you link it to me in the answers below?

Comment: Charities overtaking sites? What has the internet come to? :( FWIW, parts are still in the [google cache of it](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:e0DGxuMJ684J:www.fastcgi.com/+fastcgi&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a&source=www.google.com), and the google search excerpt is still to the FastCGI info. (Cache from May 5, 2011 21:48:13 GMT so ... IDK, mis-configured server?)

Comment: still available in google cache.. I suggest contacting people from the contact info in the google cached version of the page.